# Access-Control-Allow-Origin not set in Response

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

i tried a couple of ways to set the CORS header:

- Adding my own servlet filter
- Using com.thetransactioncompany.cors-filer
- Using Springs WebMvcConfigurer Bean

Nothing worked!!!

Can some one help me. Here the first method...

web.xml

```
<!-- Spring Container -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>de.hotelonlineportal.config.AppConfig</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Device Detection -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>deviceResolverRequestFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceResolverRequestFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<!-- Rest Dispatcher -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>rest-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rest-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- CORS Filter -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>cors-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>de.hotelonlineportal.security.CORSFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>cors-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

CORSFilter.java

```
public class CORSFilter implements Filter {

    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(CORSFilter.class);

    public CORSFilter() {
        logger.info("SimpleCORSFilter init");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS,DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me");

        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

If invoke a HTTP request the filter got applied successfully but still the repsonse does not contain any Access-Control* header.

Chrome debugger shows me this in console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://localhost:8080/hop-backend/rest/shop/listHotelsLandingPage. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

Comment: If you log request.getHeader("Origin"), is anything there? For debugging purposes, have you tried setting the header Access-Control-Allow-Origin to *?

Comment: Check your server logs.

Comment: request.getHeader("Origin") shows me http://localhost:9000. I also tried the wildcard *.

Comment: The rest webservice i tried to call is buggy and throws an exception. Interesstingly only at this service call then the CORS information is not set in the HTTP response. Once fixing the rest service the cors header is set correctly. Why does this happen?

Comment: The exception seems to occure during un-/marshalling at Jackson API due to lazy fetching using proxies.But still i dont undestand why this has impact on the HTTP header.  Could not write content: could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->de.hotelonlineportal.entity.Hotel["provider"]->de.hotelonlineportal.entity.Provider_$$_jvst6de_2["id"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain...

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting you are using tomcat.
Try using the [tomcat-CORSFilter](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter).

Using filter and init-param as below:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
    <param-value>*</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
    <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
    <param-value>10</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<!-- CORS Filter -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>cors-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>de.hotelonlineportal.security.CORSFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>cors-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```